# How to "break" IO action in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to have the "return" (in imperative language) function in haskell.

E.g.

```
main = do
  let a = 10
  print a
--  return this function
  print $ a + 1
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you wanting an "early exit" behavior?

Comment: You can't do this with `IO` alone.  You can do it by combining it with `ErrorT` or `ContT`.  Or you can use `Exception`s.

Comment: @bheklilr Yes. I need it when I debug my program sometime

Comment: @worldterminator As Rufflewind says, this isn't possible in general with `IO`, but some Monads are.  In particular, look at [`MonadPlus`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) for a typeclass that defines the behavior of exiting early.  As you can see, `IO` is not one of those that implements this typeclass.  You could look at the [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html) typeclass for another implementation from the `mtl` library, which defines the behavior to raise an error with several instances

Comment: Note that if you want this for interrupting execution while debugging, [GHCi has a builtin debugger](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) with breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can emulate this to some extent using [`Exception`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Exception.html),

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

data MyException = MyException deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception MyException

main = handle (\ MyException -> return ()) $ do
  let a = 10 :: Int
  print a
  throwIO MyException
  print $ a + 1         -- never gets executed
```

You can also do it with the [`ContT` or `ErrorT` monad transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl), although they can a bit unwieldly.

Comment: While you can indeed throw exceptions to alter the flow of your program, using them to shape the correct behaviour of it is bad design. Exceptions are for exceptional behaviour. If you need to do this then you should refactor your function instead. Be functional, not imperative.

Comment: @mariop: I would argue that it is _you_ that is looking at exceptions from an imperative viewpoint. Haskell "exceptions" are just the `Either e` monad with some additional semantics, and monads are an excellent choice for modeling control flow. Although I agree with you that the OP is trying to write imperative code in Haskell as if it were <generic imperative language> and is likely misguided in their use of exceptions _in this case_.

Comment: @mariop: I'm not advocating the use of this.  I'm just showing it can be done.  Whether it's a good practice or not is another question.

Comment: @cdk I don't agree with the comparison of `Either e` with exceptions. `Either e` is explicit, exceptions are implicit and that's a huge difference. Use `Either` for errors and normal behaviours and exceptions for exceptional behaviours.

Comment: @Rufflewind ok, but, even if correct, I still think this isn't a good answer. What you have shown is something that shouldn't be done and there is a reason. In my opinion, it is better to explain why there isn't an "imperative return" in Haskell and why this is good.

Comment: @mariop: I didn't realize that these are asynchronous exceptions in the `IO` monad, rather than explicit, synchronous exceptions in an `ErrorT` or `EitherT` monad. I was a little hasty in reading Rufflewind's answer. In this context, of course you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me start by warning that trying to translate imperative constructs into Haskell will likely lead to code which is not idiomatic, hard to write, and hard to read. Just because you can simulate some constructs by using a few monad transformers, it does not mean that this should actually be done.

That being said, here's an example of early return using `Control.Monad.Cont.ContT`. The code below simulates an imperative return inside a few for loops.

As [Rufflewind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440302/rufflewind) warns, this can get unwieldy. The type of `callCC` alone (not shown below) can be quite puzzling.

```
import Control.Monad.Cont

search :: Int -> IO (Maybe (Int,Int))
search x = runContT (callCC go) return
  where go earlyReturn = do
           forM_ [10..50] $ \i -> do
              lift $ putStrLn $ "Trying i=" ++ show i
              forM_ [10..50] $ \j -> do
                lift $ putStrLn $ "Trying j=" ++ show j
                when (i * j == x) $ do
                   lift $ putStrLn $ "Found " ++ show (i,j)
                   earlyReturn $ Just (i,j)
           return Nothing
```